# Golangでページを再読み込みするとWebsocket Serverが落ちる

Tags: javascript, html, go, websocket

GoとWebsocketの練習として写真を投稿するWebアプリケーションを作っています。
写真の投稿などはうまくできるのですが、
一度、ブラウザがhtmlを読み込んだ後、もう一度ブラウザにhtmlを再読み込み(更新)させると、`websocket.JSON.Receive`が`EOF`となりServerが落ちてしまいます。
なぜこのようなことが起こるのでしょうか?

ajaxを使ってもこのWeb Applicationは作れると思いますが、今回は練習のため、意図的にWebSocketを使いました。

Serverのコード

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-gorp/gorp"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Picture struct {
    Id   int64
    Data []byte
    Name string
}

var debug = true

var photodb = "./db/photo.sqlite3"

func main() {
    http.Handle("/layouts/css/", http.StripPrefix("/layouts/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("layouts/css"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/chat", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        s := websocket.Server{Handler: websocket.Handler(data_handle)}
        s.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    })
    fmt.Println(":8249")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8249", nil)
}

func InitDb() (*gorp.DbMap, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", photodb)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.SqliteDialect{}}
    dbmap.AddTableWithName(Picture{}, "picture").SetKeys(true, "Id")
    err = dbmap.CreateTablesIfNotExists()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return dbmap, nil
}

func insertPic(pic *Picture) {
    dbmap, err := InitDb()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("InitDb error:", err)
    }
    err = dbmap.Insert(pic)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Insert error:", err)
    }
}

func data_receive(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        var b Picture
        if err := websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &b); err != nil {
            if debug {
                fmt.Println(b)
            }
            log.Fatalln("Receive error: ", err)
        } else {
            insertPic(&b)
            err = websocket.JSON.Send(ws, b)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Send error:", err)
            }
        }
    }
}

func data_handle(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    data_receive(ws)
}
```

JavaScript

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8249/chat")
var img = document.getElementById("img");
var f = document.getElementById("file");
var file_reader = new FileReader();
f.onchange = function () {
    var filelist = this.files;
    var file = filelist[0];
    file_reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var b64 = data.slice(data.indexOf(",") + 1);
        var s = {"Name": file.name, "Data": b64};
        console.log(s);
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(s));

    }
    file_reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    var obj = console.log(e.data);

}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <title>Websocket json</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
        <img id="img">
        <script src="websocket_json.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

画面をリロードすると一旦接続が切れるため、`Receive`は`EOF`を返します。
これは正常な動作なので、エラーは出さずにループを抜けてください。

サーバーが落ちるのは`log.Fatalln`を使っているせいです。
この関数はメッセージを表示したあと、自動的にプログラムを異常終了させます。
名前の通り致命的なエラーが発生した時に使ってください。